# making 3 by 3, 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing

Hi I was just working with arrays and I had few problems with creating a 2D array in a 3 by 3 grid.

Below is an example of 1D arrray that I created with 9 buttons which is working fine atm, as it displays all 9 of the buttons.

```
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        frame.add(buttons[i]);
        buttons[i].setText(".");
```

However, when I try doing this with 2D array only 6 out of 12 buttons show up.

```
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
            JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++){
        buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
        frame.add(buttons[i][j]);
        buttons[i][j].setText(".");

        }
    }
```

Also, I have one more question, to call each individual button do I need to do it like this?

```
button[0].setText("button 1");
```

and also would it be possible to give each button a name, for example instead of button[0], would it be possible to have button1, and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the loops. You have `i++` in both.

Comment: if you want to the component to have a name, use `setName`.. `setText` is the text show in the button

Comment: Also keep in mind a 3x3 2D array is not large enough to hold 12 buttons.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that 3x3 would be 9 buttons? and not 12. And much less, not 12x12 as the second example suggests. Either way, its better coding to say `j < buttons[i].length` (and im not going to mention caching that... oops i just did)

Comment: ye, sorry about that 3 by 3 only holds 9 buttons thanks.

Comment: ya, you need to declare something like `JButton[] buttons = new JButton[3][3]`

Comment: @PimpTrizkit, hi ye, I have changed that.

Comment: @nachokk, hi so if I use setName, would I be able to refer to buttons with the name I give them or would I need to call them from the array like; buttons[0].

Comment: If you use setName you can use getName to get a buttons name. You would still have to refer to them from the array.  Or, you could declare a button as `JButton button0 = new Button()` then add it to your array as `buttons[0]=button0`.  Then you have a separate reference that you could use, but you would need to declare them all separately.

Comment: If you use an array not.. but you can distinct a button from each other, example you have `buttons[0][0].getName().equals("button1")`  then you know what button is, if you don't want to do this you still can store your buttons instead of array in a `Map<String,JButton>`

Comment: @PimpTrizkit should be `JButton[][] buttons = ..`

Comment: @nachokk -- ooops, typeo, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug here:

```
for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; i++){
```

should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++){
```

For your other questions:

Yes, you need to invoke `button[...].setText("...");` for each button to assign it's name.  (you can incorporate your loop indexes to automate this).

> and also would it be possible to give each button a name, for example instead of button[0], would it be possible to have button1, and so on.

That's why you created an array to avoid dealing with multiple object button1, button2, etc. This is because now you can process them in a loop.

**EDIT:**
also there is a problem with your array init:

> JButton[] buttons = new JButton[12];

This creates a 1-dimension array. What you want is something like:

> JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[3][3]; //[3][4] ?

**EDIT2:**

```
int number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < buttons[0].length; j++){  //watch here for additional index [0] in length (it is size of "second dimension")
        buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
        frame.add(buttons[i][j]);
        buttons[i][j].setText("Button" + number);
        number++; //in separate line for clarity
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Changing i++ to j++ creates 36 buttons in the 3 by 3 grid.

Comment: I have changed the size of array to 9 buttons which works fine now.

Comment: But could you please show me how I can give each button a name, such as button1 button2 button3 .... button9

Comment: use button[0].setName("button0") - similar to setText()

Comment: so if I use setName, would I be able to refer to buttons with the name I give them or would I need to call them from the array like; buttons[0].

Comment: and also, say for example, if i want to settext to the button, would I need to use the button name or call it from the array?

Comment: just do `JButton button1 = button[0]`  but this is considered bad coding, using an array allows you to use a loop.

Comment: would it be possible to do do something like this? String[] name = {"button1", "button2", "button3", "button4", "button5", "button6", "button7", "button8", "button9"}; loop through each name in this array and set the name of each button according to the name in the array.

Comment: This is considered as bad coding because you shouldn't access them separately by "reference" (not name). What if you have 100 buttons? Do you still want to reference them separately by button1,button2,...,button100 ? You keep them all in one, simple array. If a button is somehow important among others then assign it i.e. `JButton buttonOK = button[0]` that's fine

Comment: As far as `setText` it would normally be `button[0].setText("0")` and that only changes the text that the users sees on the button, not the the reference name you use in java. `setName` also doesn't change the reference name you use in java, in fact, you may never need to use `setName` most of the time.

Comment: oh ok, one more question, since I have 2D array will the buttons still be represented as 0, 1, 2 .... 8 in both array [][].

Comment: You `can't` change reference using loop in Java (unless without some sophisticated reflection(?)). And you shouldn't.

Comment: they will be `buttons[0][0]`, `buttons[0][2]` , `buttons[2][2]`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am just going to try it out and I be back to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: This is not `both` arrays. It is just one 2-dimensional array. And depends how you use setText method. - let me edit anwer

Comment: @Fazovsky, say for example I have a method that I want to use on each of the button with in the for loop, how would I do that?

Comment: Oh, that's why you want to keep them on array. You use loop (2 loops for 2-dimensional array) like in your code `for(...){ for(...)` then you refer to a button using loops' indexes: `button[i][j].anyMethod()` or `myMethod( button[i][j] );`

Comment: so if my method accepts parameter/s would I be able to put them in? button[i][j].anyMethod(parameter);

Comment: Yes, you can use any method with any parameters. You may also pass the button to a method. Magic :P

Comment: Thanks for the help!, is it possible to call the full array, which has all the buttons without calling it like buttons[0], ......, buttons[8].

Comment: You use loops to e.g. invoke a method for ALL buttons. That's what loops are for. You don't use `buttons[0][0]`, `buttons[0][1]`! OK, I'm off to home. Hope you understand the concept!

Answer (score 6):

Your second `for` loop has `for (int j = 0; j < buttons.length; i++)`...it should be `j++`, not `i++`.

Also, like turbo pointed out, a 3x3 grid isn't large enough to hold 12 buttons (I'm assuming you mean 4x3 or 3x4?). Also, instead of comparing both `i` and `j` to buttons.length, you should probably have two separate variables to compare each against (buttonsWidth, buttonsLength; buttonsX, buttonsY, etc.).

Comment: ye, sorry about that 3 by 3 only holds 9 buttons thanks.